# Release Failure from TFS CI

Tags: azure, tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I am trying to deploy an application to the Azure Service Fabric using the release definition task.  When it gets to the task to deploy the server is returning the following error:

The type initializer for 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.Constants' threw an exception

I checked the Endpoint configuration and it appears to be set up as it is supposed to be:

No Authentication (this is an internal text box)
Cluster endpoint: tcp://[service fabric server]:19000

It downloads the artifacts without a problem, but in deploy it searches for the paths for publish profile and application package and finds them.  After it finds them it throws the error.  I have tried replacing TCP in the endpoint with http, added and removed the :19000 as well and all I get is this error.  I have been searching online with little success.  Any help to this end is much appreciated.

John

Comment: There must be an InnerException in the TypeInitializer exception. Find out what it is.

Comment: Which authentication of Azure Service Fabric connection (service endpoint) no authentication, Azure Active Directory Credentials or Certificate Based? What's the detail build log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of researching trying every suggestion I could find, we decided try and connect to the machine via Powershell on the box and it too was returning this error.  So we uninstalled the SDK and re-installed it and the connection could be made and the builds started to work.  I don't know exactly why it failed, but apparently a re-install did the trick.  It may have been a bad install, or it could have been a versioning problem.  Either way, try a re-install first.